# Read and write data in Firebase from Apps Script - in a secure way

Tags: security, firebase, google-apps-script, firebase-realtime-database, google-sheets

My goal was to create a table (Google Sheets) that presents some data from Firebase DB - in a readable way.

Goal achieved using this awesome tutorial:
https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase/tutorials/read-and-write-data-in-firebase-from-apps-script

The thing is that this sheet presents a security/privacy hazard - since the "DB secret" is shown in the script. I can't share this sheet/script because of this.

Is there a way, without writing a web-app, to utilize Google Apps Script (with Google Sheets) in a secure way?
Maybe by adding some kind of "login" mechanism?
Or restricting access to some users (identified by their email)?

Comment: Updated my answer in response to Frank van Puffelen's comment.

Answer (score 2):

Y̶o̶u̶ ̶c̶o̶u̶l̶d̶ ̶m̶o̶v̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶s̶e̶n̶s̶i̶t̶i̶v̶e̶ ̶c̶o̶d̶e̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶a̶ ̶s̶t̶a̶n̶d̶-̶a̶l̶o̶n̶e̶ ̶s̶c̶r̶i̶p̶t̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶d̶e̶p̶l̶o̶y̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶a̶s̶ ̶a̶ ̶[̶l̶i̶b̶r̶a̶r̶y̶]̶[̶1̶]̶.̶ ̶Y̶̶̶o̶u̶ ̶c̶a̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶n̶ ̶r̶e̶f̶e̶r̶e̶n̶c̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶l̶i̶b̶r̶a̶r̶y̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶t̶a̶i̶n̶e̶r̶-̶b̶o̶u̶n̶d̶ ̶s̶c̶r̶i̶p̶t̶s̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶o̶n̶l̶y̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶'̶l̶l̶ ̶e̶x̶p̶o̶s̶e̶ ̶a̶r̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶s̶i̶g̶n̶a̶t̶u̶r̶e̶s̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶c̶o̶d̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶r̶e̶i̶n̶ ̶k̶e̶e̶p̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶"̶D̶B̶ ̶S̶e̶c̶r̶e̶t̶"̶ ̶s̶a̶f̶e̶.

Y̶o̶u̶ ̶c̶a̶n̶ ̶e̶v̶e̶n̶ ̶a̶d̶d̶ ̶e̶x̶t̶r̶a̶ ̶s̶e̶c̶u̶r̶i̶t̶y̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶c̶r̶e̶a̶t̶e̶ ̶a̶ ̶w̶h̶i̶t̶e̶-̶l̶i̶s̶t̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶u̶s̶e̶r̶s̶,̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶g̶a̶t̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶c̶o̶d̶e̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶l̶i̶b̶r̶a̶r̶y̶ ̶s̶u̶c̶h̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶a̶c̶c̶e̶s̶s̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶o̶n̶l̶y̶ ̶g̶r̶a̶n̶t̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶t̶h̶o̶s̶e̶ ̶o̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶l̶i̶s̶t̶ ̶s̶i̶n̶c̶e̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶'̶l̶l̶ ̶b̶e̶ ̶a̶b̶l̶e̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶d̶e̶t̶e̶c̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶c̶u̶r̶r̶e̶n̶t̶ ̶u̶s̶e̶r̶ ̶v̶i̶a̶ ̶`̶S̶e̶s̶s̶i̶o̶n̶.̶g̶e̶t̶A̶c̶t̶i̶v̶e̶U̶s̶e̶r̶(̶)̶.̶g̶e̶t̶E̶m̶a̶i̶l̶(̶)̶`̶.

***Update 1***

Verified @Frank van Puffelen comment, and he is correct in that a library's code can be exposed by linking to the stand-alone script directly. For a user to be able to use a library they need at minimum view-only access, which allows them to see the code using a direct link to the stand-alone script.

But here is a viable solution, you can deploy your script as an [add-on](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/) and that will ensure that your code remains private. Your users will have to install the add-on to use your script but they won't have access to the code.

---

***Update 2***

I believe libraries could still be viable for your use-case, but you'd have to go about using them in a round-about sort of way.

So here's how you might go about it:

> - *Create, not one, but **two** libraries.*
> - *Share one of those libraries publicly so that your users can access it. Lets call this library **LIB_A**.*
> - *Store any sensitive data and functionality in the second library; let's call it **LIB_B**.*
> - *Have **LIB_A** reference **LIB_B**. Because **LIB_A** and **LIB_B** both belong to the same account, **LIB_A** can access the contents of **LIB_B**. However, the contents of **LIB_B** will not be exposed
>     to your users (as long as it is not shared).*

Note that this approach is not without its downsides, your app takes a performance hit whenever you use libraries so the more libraries you use the slower your executions times. So if you have time-critical code in play this may not be the best approach.

Comment: Isn't it always possible to see the code for libraries with the approach shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31993969/how-can-i-view-the-source-of-a-google-apps-script-library)?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Didn't consider that. Updated my answer to suggest add-ons instead.

Comment: Thanks for the original ideas (using a library on an add-on).

Still not very happy with this all "secret" approach.
I wonder if there's a way to authenticate users using a specific sheet, running a specific script - so that there won't be a need to use this secret mechanism...

If not, I guess there won't be any option but writing a web app which access FireBase...